# Laravel 5.1: Retrieve method(s) for route name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to get the method(s) that a route responds to by its name? The UrlGenerator (as I would expect by its name in all fairness), only provides the URL given a route name. Is there a service provider that can return both the URL and any methods that the route can respond to? I would prefer not to have to hook directly into the app's route collection if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you to go about this would be to extend the UrlGenerator. You could then add a new method to return an array of the HTTP methods allowed for a route.

```php
public function getMethodsForRoute($name)
{
    if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name)))
    {
        return $route->methods();
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
}
```

As an alternative you may be able to get the current route from the router and return them that way. Its slightly less elegant, however. (Note this is untested)

```php
$name = 'route.name';

$router = app('Illuminate\Routing\Router');

if (! is_null($route = $router->getRoutes()->getByName($name)))
{
    $methods = $route->methods();
}
```

Comment: Would it perhaps be better to add to the applications RouteServiceProvider, so I'm not changing any built in service providers? I can access the Router from there too.

Comment: If you're extending the UrlGenerator I would suggest creating a new service provider that registers your extended version of the UrlGenerator.